# Plug valve problem

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, pipelines, valves, petroleum-engineering

A pig is a solid plug that is introduced into the pipeline to be serviced. Fluid is pumped upstream of the pig to provide the necessary force to set the device in motion, and to perform
the desired task. We are trying to find a suitable pig, this pig can pass through the 6" plug valve. We found that the pig can mainly pass through the ball valve and the sphere valve, but because of the equipment, we want to know if we can use a suitable pig to pass the 6" plug valve?
Another question is, the pig will pass through the curved pipeline in the pipeline, how to make the pig pass through these curved pipelines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “The pig will pass through the curved pipeline” then you suggest it won’t. What are you saying?

Answer (score 1):

If  the plug (or any other type) valve is full bore the pig should pass. Full bore valves are common in oil production , well head valves in particular are full bore. There are many types of pigs your statement that they are solid plugs in incorrect.